# ITextSharp using multiple font styles together. ie Bold, Underlined, italic... etc

Tags: c#, itext

I am attempting to use `Itextsharp.dll` (not sure which version) to write a dynamic PDF.  Everything was going great until I needed to write a phrase with that is bold and underlined.  However it appears that itextSharp's font class does not allow for this.  It allows for bold/italic, but not bold/underline, italic/ underline, or all three. You cannot combine underlined with any other style. It seems rather silly to not allow for a font to be both underlined and something else.  I have looked everywhere and see nothing that mentions it. Does anyone know a way around this or am I missing something obvious here?

I would generally build my Font like so.

```
iTextSharp.text.Font myFont = new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLDITALIC, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

You can see the 3rd parameter is an integer signifying the `FontStyle` for the font, however there are no enums available to make something underlined AND bold ,underlined AND italic, or all three. There has to be a way to do this.  I find it hard to believe that ITextSharp would not account for underlined and bold text.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the definition for [`BOLDITALIC`](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Font.cs#L93) you'll see:

```
public const int BOLDITALIC    = BOLD | ITALIC;
```

This shows you how to combine these styles using a bitwise `|` (`or`) operator. You are of course free to redefine these however you want but you'll usually see them used like this:

```
var myFont = new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 9, Font.BOLD | Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

**EDIT**

Looking at the source, `BOLD` is `1` and `UNDERLINE` is `4` and when you `|` them together you get `5` which is the same value that you posted. You can test every single combination of all 5 styles using the code below.

```
//Create a test file on our desktop
var testFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf");

//Possible styles
var styles = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
    { "NORMAL" , iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL },
    { "BOLD" , iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD },
    { "ITALIC" , iTextSharp.text.Font.ITALIC },
    { "UNDERLINE" , iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE },
    { "STRIKETHRU",  iTextSharp.text.Font.STRIKETHRU }
};

//Standard iText bootstrap
using (var fs = new FileStream(testFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    using(var doc = new Document()) {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
            doc.Open();

            //We're going to try every possible unique combination of constants, store the
            //previously used ones in this dictionary
            var used = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            //Fixed-number combination hack, just create 5 nested loops.
            foreach (var a in styles) {
                foreach (var b in styles) {
                    foreach (var c in styles) {
                        foreach (var d in styles) {
                            foreach (var g in styles) {

                                //Bitwise OR the values together
                                var k = a.Value | b.Value | c.Value | d.Value | g.Value;

                                //If we didn't previously use this OR'd value
                                if (!used.ContainsKey(k)) {

                                    //Get all of the unique names exclude duplicates
                                    var names = new string[] { a.Key, b.Key, c.Key, d.Key, g.Key }.Distinct().OrderBy(s => s).ToList();

                                    //NORMAL is the "default" and although NORMAL | BOLD is totally valid it just
                                    //messes with your brain when you see it. So remove NORMAL from the description
                                    //when it is used with anything else. This part is optional
                                    if (names.Count() > 1 && names.Contains("NORMAL")) {
                                        names = names.Where(n => n != "NORMAL").ToList();
                                    }

                                    //Merge our names into a comma-separated string
                                    var v = String.Join(", ", names);

                                    //Store it so we don't use it again
                                    used.Add(k, v);

                                    //Create a font using this loop's value
                                    var myFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, k, BaseColor.BLACK);

                                    //Add it to our document
                                    doc.Add(new Paragraph(k.ToString() + "=" + v, myFont));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This code produces this text:

[image]

Comment: I updated the above to show possible values and their outcome. The chart that you posted does not appear to be correct.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  I am not sure as to why the method you described was not working.  But I will try again when I have the patience